Hide/Show a nested Group of shapes - VBA excel
I have a group of shapes in a group "EPOtbl"
Inside group "EPOtbl" there is an another group "PotblGroup_1"
whenever i am trying to set group "PotblGroup_1" visible to false
Sheets("ePO").Shapes("POtblGroup_1").Visible = False
i get the following error: "The item with the specified name wasn't found"
is there a way to do that?

What do you mean that the group is "inside" another group?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65400944/grouping-an-array-of-shapes

@SJR Group2 contains "Shape1","Shape2" Shape3")
Group1 Contains Group2, "Shape4"

"Is there a way to do that?" Short answer: No.
In the moment you group shapes, the child shapes are removed from the Shapes-collection of the worksheet.
Example: A sheet with 5 shapes (with name Shape01..05):

Run the following code:
Sub testSub()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Dim sh As Shape
        For Each sh In .Shapes
            Debug.Print sh.Name
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Gives
shape01
shape02
shape03
shape04
shape05

Now group the first three shapes (the blue) and run the code again:

Group 15
shape04
shape05

The shapes01..03 that are part of the group are no longer elements of the Shapes-collection of the worksheet. Instead, you can access them as part of the group, using the property GroupItems:
    Dim shOuter As Shape, shInner As Shape
    For Each shOuter In .Shapes
        Debug.Print shOuter.Name, shOuter.Parent.Name
        If shOuter.Type = msoGroup Then
            For Each shInner In shOuter.GroupItems
                Debug.Print "  " & shInner.Name, shInner.ParentGroup.Name
            Next
        End If
    Next

Group 15      Sheet1
  shape01     Group 15
  shape02     Group 15
  shape03     Group 15
shape04       Sheet1
shape05       Sheet1

So far, so good - you might think "okay, I just will loop recursively over my shapes and shape groups. But.
If you now group the group plus the 2 extra shapes (green),

you will get the following output:
Group 16      Sheet1
  shape01     Group 16
  shape02     Group 16
  shape03     Group 16
  shape04     Group 16
  shape05     Group 16

The "inner" group (Group 15) is gone, it no longer exists. When you ungroup the outer group, the inner group is recreated, Excel remembers the inner group, including the name. However, as long at the outer group exists, this inner group is not accessible. The information about the existence of this inner group (name, members...) is hidden from the VBA data model. So in your case PotblGroup_1 simply does not exists.
I was curious and tried the following: I ungrouped the "Outer" group and executed the following code
Dim shGrp As Shape
Set shGrp = ws.Shapes("Group 15")
Debug.Print shGrp.Name
ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 15", "shape04", "shape05")).Group
Debug.Print shGrp.Name

The first Debug.Print - statement will print the name, but the second Print will raise a 424 error (Object required): The object is destroyed.
Only workaround I can think of is to name the shapes, eg by putting the group name as prefix (PotblGroup_1_Shape1...). Now you can use the following routine to show or hide a "group" of shapes (=all shapes with a specific prefix)
Sub showHideGroup(ws As Worksheet, groupName As String, show As Boolean)
    With ws
        Dim shOuter As Shape, shInner As Shape
        For Each shOuter In .Shapes
            If shOuter.Name Like groupName & "*" Then shOuter.Visible = show
            
            If shOuter.Type = msoGroup Then
                For Each shInner In shOuter.GroupItems
                    If shInner.Name Like groupName & "*" Then shInner.Visible = show
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

